# Vertically align images in full-height columns

Tags: html, css

Given the following layout:

```
.half-side {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.leftbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.rightbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
}

<div class="half-side">
  <div class="leftbox">
    <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_65ce634bba10_128.png" />
  </div>
</div><!--
--><div class="half-side">
  <div class="rightbox">
    <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_65ce634bba10_128.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6rr7kno/1/).

How can I vertically center my images?

As you can see, I've tried `vertical-align: middle` to no avail. To be frank, I don't really understand why this doesn't work.

I keep seeing this "trick" - and similar approaches using negative transformations - everywhere:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Which causes the images to be pushed halfway off the top of the page.

How do I vertically align the content in my two columns?

Comment: Your colums aren't full height to start with - https://jsfiddle.net/f3n0vwps/

Comment: Also, there is **no** CSS method of aligning elements that do not share a common parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, your divs don't have height so it will never know where the vertical center is. The simplest hack is to use an `inline-block` helper with `height: 100%` and `vertical-align: middle` on both elements.

Here's the full code solution:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.half-side {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.leftbox {
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightbox {
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-side">
  <div class="leftbox">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_65ce634bba10_128.png" />
  </div>
</div><!--
--><div class="half-side">
  <div class="rightbox">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/avatar_65ce634bba10_128.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Vertical centering problems are usually best solved with `display: flex`. See https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes